# How do I change the woocommerce product gallery to show all thumbnails instead of three at a time in a carousel?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, gallery, thumbnails, captions

I am building a site for a client and I can't seem to figure out how to remove the product gallery carousel setting. For the final result, I want to be able to see all the thumbnails at once and not have to use the nav arrows to cycle through. It could be displayed in a grid style setting with 3 images per row or something (preferrably) like this: http://arhitekturakrusec.si/en/. I also would like to show a caption below or above each thumbnail.

Any suggestions?

What I'm working on: http://nsrstone.jordancan.com/product/absolute-black/

Comment: Please note that questions pertaining to 3rd-party products are considered [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) within our community, and would be best addressed by the 3rd party's official support channels. In some instances you may be able to edit your question into a more generic format applicable to vanilla WordPress in order to bring it back on-topic. Please review the "[ask]" page in our [help] for more information regarding the nature of questions that work well within our community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to woocommerce folder-> template single product -> product-thumbnail.php from that you need to delete the slider class